# How to jk to navigate the "list-windows" pane in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have this function at work but at home somehow it stops working. When I try to list the windows with `prefix + w`, I can navigate the windows using up and down arrows. But I cannot with `j` and `k`. I remember this should be possible but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

unbind-key C-b
set -g prefix 'C-a'

# splitting windows
bind / split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind - split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"

set-option -g update-environment "SSH_AUTH_SOCK \
                                  SSH_CONNECTION \
                                  DISPLAY"
# Mouse mode
set-option -g mouse on

# List of plugins
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tpm'
set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-sensible'

set -g @plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
set -g @plugin 'seebi/tmux-colors-solarized'

set -g @colors-solarized 'dark'

set -g @plugin 'nhdaly/tmux-better-mouse-mode'

# Other examples:
# set -g @plugin 'github_username/plugin_name'
# set -g @plugin 'git@github.com/user/plugin'
# set -g @plugin 'git@bitbucket.com/user/plugin'

# Initialize TMUX plugin manager (keep this line at the very bottom of tmux.conf)
run '~/.tmux/plugins/tpm/tpm'
```

I am using tmux 2.5

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `mode-keys vi`

```
set-option -gw mode-keys vi   # vi style key bindings
```

Comment: @AndyAldo most of the Tmux lists are vertical... If you do Ctrl A + { to enter edit mode, then h / l do work as they do in Vi.... What other behavior are you hoping to add to h / l ?